# Unexpected changing of C++ constant integer

Tags: c++

The variable steady_counter is intialized as a constant integer.

cout << steady_counter;

So long as i have the above statement anywhere before the following code, the function runs as expected and checks if an integer input is or is not a runaround number.

The problem is that when the cout line is not present, the constant integer changes within the below if statements. I tested this by printing steady_counter before entering the if-else, and then after the if-else.

Without the cout line, steady_counter changes to a 4 digit number.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (CheckArr[i])
        {
            num_of_unique++;
        }
    }

    if ((steady_counter == num_of_unique) & (final == NumArr[0]) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going on? Why do I require a cout line to maintain the constant integer steady_counter?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). Learn about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Read more your C++ tutorials.

Comment: This is a bit of a mess. I can't understand why you chose to use a VLA. Probably accidental. Perhaps you don't know what a VLA is and are using it inadvertently. I don't understand why you don't use standard containers. You are programming in C++ not C.

Comment: @Basile hello! Could you elaborate on the 'warnings and debug info'? The above compiles without any error. Should I put in the main function with the test code?

Comment: What compiler and operating system are you using (hint: [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and Linux are good choices)?

Comment: "the code works",... what is "working" and "not working"?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6902777f71de01ba. Fix those warnings first.

Comment: @ Basile I'm using GCC with Dev-C++ 5.7.1. Also, windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: @lostlostlostlostlost: Then you should specify (at least) `-Wall -Wextra` as compiler arguments, to enable a decent set of warnings. That should catch some common bugs.

Comment: Reworded what I was asking, do I include the rest of the test code?

Answer (score 2):

One obvious problem:

```
for (int i = counter; i > 0; i --)
    NumArr[i] = -1;
```

This covers values from `1` to `counter` inclusive; while valid indexes for `NumArr` are from `0` to `counter-1` inclusive. So you write outside the array, corrupting something else; possibly another local variable.

Either correct the off-by-one error in the index

```
NumArr[i-1] = -1;
```

or use a more canonical loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
```

or, for more of a C++ flavour,

```
std::fill(NumArr, NumArr+counter, -1);
```

There are likely to be further errors, which are better found by using your debugger than by asking people to read through all your code.